# Is it possible to retrieve only the timestamp from a influxDb query

Tags: influxdb, influxql

Is it possible to pass the timestamp retuned in influxDb query to another query.

```
Select max("value")
      from "temp" where ("floor" = "1);
```

Output

```
time                 max 
----                 ---      
2020-01-17T00:00:00Z 573.44
```

Is it possible to pass the time from the result to another query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with InfluxQL,it is not possible to nest the queries in a way that could pass the time range of the inner query to the outer query. it's another matter if you were using Flux (new Query Language but still in BETA).

In Flux this is possible, because you can access time as a column, which you can then use to query your other measurements as required. You can also use JOIN to do more advanced operations like cross measurement calculations etc.